# Render Script into HTML without Executing it

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <html>

     <p> Some html </p>

     <script> some script </script>

  </html>
```

How to identify the script tag and render them as content.

I have a div dedicated to display a html in my webpage, and if it has any script I want to render them as content, but while appending the html to the div, the script gets executed which I dont want to happen. How to keep the script from executing, are there any libraries to do that.

Note:
1. The Inline script should also be prevent from executed.
2. The Html Content getting appended is dynamic and got from email listener source

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you don't want a script, don't write `<script>`. If you want the text "<script>" to render on your page, you'll have to write `&lt;script&gt;`.

Comment: You will have to use `&lt;script&gt;` instead of `<script>`.

Comment: please post the code used to append the html to the div. This behaviour is normal but can be circumvent.

Comment: This title is so misleading.

Comment: Use any other tag except the one that actually executes the script if you want to output the script code on the page.

Comment: The code that I append to the div is not something I write. Its dynamic and i get from email listener services .

Comment: @KarthikAmar let me know if my answer helps

Comment: @Reddy - your answer certainly helped, but it doesn't work with inline script. Can you please let me know of a way through which I could actually strip inline javascript

Comment: @what do you mean inline script?? You are actually appending this part of html to the div right?? so before appending you can clean up

Answer (score 4):

> but while appending the html to the div, the script gets executed which I dont want to happen. How to keep the script from executing, are there any libraries to do that.

Since you say you already have the div content and as soon as you append it the script gets executed, This is a default behavior, What we can do is before appending the div content of yours we can modify the content string to replace `<script>` and `</script>` by `&lt;script&gt;` and `&lt;/script&gt;`. So here is the demo of it.

```js
var divContent = '<script>alert("I must not execute!!");<\/script>';

var res = divContent.replace(/<script/g,"&lt;script&gt;").replace(/<\/script/g,"&lt;/script&gt;");

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<div id="output">
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sanitize the string (data) you want to render.

```js
function sanitizeHTML(str) {
  return str.replace(/[<>"'&/]/g, function (char) {
    return {
      '<': '&lt;',
      '>': '&gt;',
      '"': '&quot;',
      "'": '&#039;',
      '&': '&amp;',
      '/': '&#x2F;'
    }[char];
  });
}
```

This will do for every script and turn it in string chars.

Answer (score 0):

Use the document.ready(); method. This will only run your JavaScript once all the HTML elements have rendered. Better yet, wrap your function within the jQuery shorthand:

```
$(function() {
    alert( "DOM elements rendered!" );
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use jQuery `document.ready();` function to only allow the script to execute when the page has loaded.